# hector_gazebo_plugins build failure

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,

I'm trying to build the hector_gazebo stack (hector_gazebo version 0.1.1), but I'm getting the following compiler error:

```
[ rosmake ] Last 40 linesctor_gazebo_plugins: 42.5 sec ] [ hector_gazebo_thermal_camera: 18.2 sec ] [ gazebo_tests: 0.6 sec ]                         [ 3 Active 101/108 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [ 77%] [ 88%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_gps.dir/src/gazebo_ros_gps.cpp.o
  Building CXX object CMakeFiles/diffdrive_plugin_6w.dir/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp.o
  make[3]: Entering directory `/opt/ros/ros_ws_sim/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/build'
  [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_imu.dir/src/gazebo_ros_imu.cpp.o
  /opt/ros/ros_ws_sim/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_sonar.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void gazebo::GazeboRosSonar::Load(gazebo::sensors::SensorPtr, sdf::ElementPtr)’:
  /opt/ros/ros_ws_sim/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_sonar.cpp:88:102: warning: ‘double gazebo::math::Angle::GetAsRadian() const’ is deprecated (declared at /opt/ros/ros_ws_sim/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/include/gazebo-1.3/gazebo/math/Angle.hh:87) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  /opt/ros/ros_ws_sim/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_sonar.cpp:88:189: warning: ‘double gazebo::math::Angle::GetAsRadian() const’ is deprecated (declared at /opt/ros/ros_ws_sim/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/include/gazebo-1.3/gazebo/math/Angle.hh:87) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  /opt/ros/ros_ws_sim/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_imu.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void gazebo::GazeboRosIMU::Update()’:
  /opt/ros/ros_ws_sim/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_imu.cpp:290:91: warning: ‘double gazebo::math::Vector3::GetDotProd(const gazebo::math::Vector3&) const’ is deprecated (declared at /opt/ros/ros_ws_sim/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/include/gazebo-1.3/gazebo/math/Vector3.hh:126) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  /opt/ros/ros_ws_sim/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_imu.cpp:291:85: warning: ‘gazebo::math::Vector3 gazebo::math::Vector3::GetCrossProd(const gazebo::math::Vector3&) const’ is deprecated (declared at /opt/ros/ros_ws_sim/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/include/gazebo-1.3/gazebo/math/Vector3.hh:120) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  /opt/ros/ros_ws_sim/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp: In member function ‘void gazebo::DiffDrivePlugin6W::publish_odometry()’:
  /opt/ros/ros_ws_sim/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp:308:3: error: ‘btQuaternion’ was not declared in this scope
  /opt/ros/ros_ws_sim/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp:308:16: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘qt’
  /opt/ros/ros_ws_sim/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp:309:3: error: ‘btVector3’ was not declared in this scope
  /opt/ros/ros_ws_sim/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp:309:13: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘vt’
  /opt/ros/ros_ws_sim/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp:310:40: error: ‘qt’ was not declared in this scope
  /opt/ros/ros_ws_sim/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp:310:44: error: ‘vt’ was not declared in this scope
  Linking CXX shared library ../lib/libreset_plugin.so
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/ros_ws_sim/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/build'
  [100%] Built target reset_plugin
  make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/diffdrive_plugin_6w.dir/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp.o] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/ros_ws_sim/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/diffdrive_plugin_6w.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Has anyone encountered this error when building from source? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated since I'm fairly new to ROS and ROS simulations. Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54621/hector_gazebo_plugins-build-failure/) by [Donny3000](https://answers.ros.org/users/3991/donny3000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2013-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `btQuaternion`/`btVector3` bug was a leftover from the conversion of the plugin from ROS electric to fuerte. It was already fixed in [r679](https://code.google.com/p/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/source/detail?r=679) two months ago. Obviously at the time of the 0.1.1 relase of the [hector_gazebo](http://ros.org/wiki/hector_gazebo) stack, usage of the old bullet datatypes did not cause a compilation error.

Today we released [version 0.1.2](http://tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/tags/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo-0.1.2/) of the stack (check the [ChangeList](http://ros.org/wiki/hector_gazebo/ChangeList)). You should either use this one or the latest version from [trunk](http://tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/hector_gazebo).

---

Originally posted by [Johannes Meyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1634/johannes-meyer/) with karma: 1266 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Donny3000](https://answers.ros.org/users/3991/donny3000/) on 2013-02-07**:
Thanks Johannes for the reply! I will go ahead and check out the 0.1.2 version of the stack.